# Re-using a Class by slightly modifying it without copying the class and renaming it

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

Ok i've been reading SO for awhile and there are brilliant people here which is why i'm kind of embarrassed and a little intimidated about asking this CSS question, I risk being laughed at in exchange for increasing my knowledge so here goes.

I've been trying to wrap my brain around a concept that is probably a cinch for most of the people on SO but reading CSS books and tons of online tuts still has not brought clarity to me on this matter.

When I create a website as a design there are obviously many repeating styles but here's my biggest problem when re-using styles that don't match exactly what i need for that particular page of a design.

For example I create an "h1", "h2", "p" rule that is pretty much the same across the board, if i need to alter it I simply create a class or use a span tag when i have to modify these tags for a particular parts of a design, don't know if that's the best way to handle it, but that's what i've been doing to get by.

But what's even worse is that i create containers for primary and secondary content within my main body div and for each page i create i basically copy the div (id or class) from a previous page (that i had done the markup for) and just change the name so that i can modify it without messing up the same divs or classes on the other pages i copied them from.

And this seems like too much CSS but i can't figure out how else to modify a class or id to suite my needs on a particular page. So that's the explanation, here is some of my actual CSS that I over complicate:

A page called: Products & Pricing --

```
    <div id="primaryContent_pp">
         <h1 id="introHeader">Products & Pricing</h1>
         <p id="introText">...generic text...</p>   
             <img id="serversImg" alt="..."></img>      
    </div><!---end primaryContent_pp--->
```

A page called: Support --

```
    <div id="primaryContent_support">
             <h1 id="introHeader">Support</h1>
             <p id="introText">...generic text..</p> 
             <img id="supportImg" alt="..."></img>     

    </div><!---end primaryContent_support--->
```

A page called: Contact --

```
    <div id="primaryContent_contact">
             <h1 id="introHeader">Contact Us</h1>
             <p id="introText">...generic text...</p> 
             <img id="contactImg" alt="..."></img>     

    </div><!---end primaryContent_contact--->
```

So you see what i'm doing here?

I'm creating a separate rule for every pages primaryContent div because I fear that if I have to alter it's size or padding i'll messup all the other divs on the other pages that have the same id or class and in my attempt to not do that i just duplicate the rule and change it without fear because i know it won't affect another div or rule but it's just plain stupid because i'm writing so much CSS and not stepping my game up because i'm clouded with senselessness.

You may also notice that I didn't alter the (h1 id="introHeader") nor (p id="introText") because I have faith that someone here can show me the light as to how to go around not having to create a new "h1" rule or "p" rule for every page in case i wanted to change that divs width, height, padding, margin, float, etc.

Can anyone help me bring an end to my blindness and bring logic to my madness so that i can learn once and for all how to not worry about re-using id's and class' knowing that there is a simpler logic to what i'm doing?

I do know that ID's can only be used once per page and class as many times as needed but what i'm doing is just too much css, that must have a simpler way to edit it's styling on a per page basis instead of having to copy that rule and rename it so that i can edit things like padding, margin, text-alignment, float, width, height, etc without fearing that it will break something somewhere else.

Does this make sense? Sorry for the long-winded explanation, and thanks for taking the time to pour your knowledge on me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Tag your HTML semantically, e.g.:
   Products: `<body id="products"> ... </body>`
   Support: `<body id="support"> ... </body>`
2. Make one-off modifications as needed in your CSS

   ```css
   #introHeader                { /* common styles */ }
   body#products #introHeader  { /* page-specific tweaks */ }
   body#support  #introHeader  { /* page-specific tweaks */ }
   ```

Only override what you absolutely must on a per-page basis, leaving the common styles to be inherited from a single source.

Comment: I have one comment to your answer though, its not related to this question. In your answer body#products selector is over qualified. just #products, #support should do well, as id is unique in a page.

Comment: @rajkamal That's correct, except in the possibly case where you accidentally create a page with a `#support` id somewhere else (which still wouldn't match, of course, unless you put an `#introHeader` in there as well). I personally find it more self-documenting to have the `body` tag specified to clarify to the casual observer the page-level scoping that is in play.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd recommend *not* using ids to style content. Ids are best used to provide navigation and script-hooks. If you use ids for that purpose, and classes for styling, then you can change ids and classes all you want without worrying that either a script or styling will stop working. Separation of concerns. Furthermore, you avoid specificity problems, which is always a bonus.

Now, I would try to develop a deeper understanding of what you are trying to achieve here. Basically, you have module, or set of tags, that always look the same. However, on some pages, you might want to fiddle with margin and paddings (and perhaps other properties as well).

So I would do it like this instead.

1. Create a generic case
2. Add additional classes that (borrowing from OOCSS syntax) **extends** your generic case

Generic markup:

```
<div class="content">
     <h1 class="content-header">Content header</h1>
     <p class="content-text">...generic text...</p>   
     <img id="serversImg" alt="..."></img>      
</div>
```

Extended markup, with script hooks and additional styling possibilities:

```
<div id="primaryContent_contact" class="content content-contact">
     <h1 class="content-header">Contact Us</h1>
     <p class="content-text">...generic text...</p> 
     <img id="contactImg" alt="..."></img>     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.content-header {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.content-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.content-contact .content-header {
  color: red;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `class` that you would apply to all three divs. Then give each individual div a unique `id`. You would apply the styles that are the same for each div to the `class` and the styles that are separate for each div to the `ids`. See Below.

```
<div class="primaryContent" id="pp">
     <h1>Products & Pricing</h1>
     <p>...generic text...</p>   
     <img src="..." alt="..."></img>      
</div><!---end .primaryContent#pp--->

<div class="primaryContent" id="support">
     <h1>Support</h1>
     <p>...generic text...</p>   
     <img src="..." alt="..."></img>      
</div><!---end .primaryContent#support--->

<div class="primaryContent" id="contact">
     <h1>Support</h1>
     <p>...generic text...</p>   
     <img src="..." alt="..."></img>      
</div><!---end .primaryContent#contact--->
```

Your CSS would look like:

```
.primaryContent{
    ...rules that are the same for all divs goes here...
}
#pp{
    ...rules for first div goes here...
}
#support{
    ...rules for second div goes here...
}
#contact{
    ...rules for third div goes here...
}
```

You can target the elements inside like:

```
.primaryContent h1{
    ...rulles for all primaryContent h1s goes here...
}
```

You would specify each inner element that has the same rules by simply switching out the `h1` tag. `.primaryContent p` would target all p elements inside any element with a class of `.primaryContent`. To specify an individual inner element switch `.primaryContent` with the `id` you wish to specify. `#contact h1` would target the `h1` tag inside the element with the id of `#contact`.

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets. This means that any rule that appears further down the page will take precedence over a duplicate rule higher up on the page. Also more specific declarations will take precedence over less specific declarations.

Hope that helps! We have all started somewhere and asking questions is the only way to learn!

Post your CSS if you need more help.